# The image renders, but the image editor with the rendered image does not show in the interface

Tags: rendering

I have just installed Blender 2.81 and I can't view a rendered image. I press F12 and it runs through the motions but nothing show at the end of the process. I have tried selecting view animation or F 11 and nothing happens, am I missing something obvious? I go back to Blender 2.80 and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

found the solution!

I had to update the preferences and change 'Render in' from 'keep user interface' to 'image editor' See pic.
[image: solution]